# Where can one find source archives of old SQLite versions?

Tags: sqlite

The [downloads](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) page on [www.sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org) appears to only have links to the current version, and I would like to get a previous version.  I cannot see any obvious links to historical versions on the site and (unless I'm missing something obvious) there does not appear to be a sourceforge project.

Can someone point me at an archive of old SQLite source releases if such a thing exists?

Nigel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Direct Access To The Sources**

Also, if you want to compile yourself.  Access to all SQLite source code is maintained in a CVS repository that is available for read-only access by anyone. You can interactively view the repository contents and download individual files by visiting [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/dir?d=sqlite)

Also

[www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?t=release](http://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?t=release) will show when every sqlite version was released.

Checkout from cvs from the date you want and compile. Instruction how to checkout from cvs are [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
Note: Use the -D option to checkout by date

Comment: The link is now obsolete and only gives revisions up to 3.6.17. Current timeline seems to be on http://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline, but that has latest revisions. There is a list of tags at http://www.sqlite.org/src/taglist, but that only has things since 3.7.2 and list of branches at http://www.sqlite.org/src/brlist, which seems to have the rest, but it's not completely clear, because they are branches and may have moved after the release.

Comment: Could somebody please compile a Windows SQLite client 3.6.x for me? I just want one for a quick test but missed to download it as it was current. Now I've got none.

Answer (score 15):

I found this in their old message list archives. Hopefully this helps:

> Older version of SQLite are aviable
>   from the website, but there are no 
>   direct links on the web pages. You
>   need to manually edit the links to 
>   get the file you need.
>
> The 2.1 version of the database file
>   implies that it was created with a 
>   2.X.Y version of SQLite. You should get the latest version which is 
>   2.8.17 (I believe).
>
> If you go the download page
>   http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
>   and the  right click on the link to
>   download the latest Windows binary
>   file, then
>
> select Copy Link Location (at least
>   using Firefox, in IE the command is 
>   Copy Shortcut). Now open a new tab or
>   window and paste the link into the
>
> address bar. You can edit the link and
>   replace the version number with  the
>   version you want to download. In your
>   case you need to change 
>   http://www.sqlite.org/sqlitedll-3_5_6.zip
>   to 
>   http://www.sqlite.org/sqlitedll-2_8_17.zip
>   and then press enter to start

Comment: Doesn't work. They seem to have updated their website some time ago and forgot to keep the old files.

Comment: @LonelyPixel Good catch. It appears they are now using a Fossil repository to store their old versions, and you need to follow their links to get to it. Scroll down to the very bottom of the downloads link above to see the repository links. It doesn't look pretty, but feasible if you really need to get the code.

Comment: thanks DO! e.g. looking for 2.8.17 - went to the source repo, selected timeline, did a search on 'version-2.8.17', navigated to the check-in for that release, which yielded a page with a tarball & zip.

Comment: @theRiley's comment should be answer (as of now atleast) :)

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is kind of old but there's an easier way to get the URL to the older zip files.

Using a combination of answers here, you can calculate the download URL of the zip file for the specific version you want.

1. Determine the version number you want to get  (we'll use 3.8.7.4 as an example)
2. Look on the timeline (http://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?t=release) to figure out the year in which your desired version was released (3.8.7.4 was released in 2014)
3. Normalize the version number into exactly 7 digits.  Expand each piece into 2 digits with leading zeroes except for the initial 3 which should remain 1 digit.   For example 3.8.7.4  becomes 3080704.  3.13.0 becomes 3130000.  (If there is no 4th period delimited piece, use 00)
4. Using your normalized version number, plug it into one of these formats, depending on what you're looking for (Replace the text '7DIGITS' in the urls below with your normalized version number, replace the text YEAR with the year in which the version was released

Source:       http://www.sqlite.org/YEAR/sqlite-src-7DIGITS.zip

Amalgamated:  http://www.sqlite.org/YEAR/sqlite-amalgamation-7DIGITS.zip

So our example versions become 
http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-src-3080704.zip and http://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-amalgamation-3080704.zip

I haven't tried this for every version but my 3 test versions worked. I would imagine the other download types (like precompiled binaries, documentation, etc) work as well.

Comment: Just remind this method currently works not before the year of 2013, the earliest version is 3.7.16, before this version, need to looking into other methods

Answer (score 3):

The idea from TomWitt2 is fantastic (I had spent hours to find solution) but now the links seems to be have modified so follow below steps to get your archived version:

1. Get the latest version link from the download page here http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
2. Get your normalized 7 digit number as mentioned in answer by TomWitt2
3. Just replace the number in the link and you are ready to go

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a few solutions on this page and elsewhere, all that I've seen seem outdated and no longer work. I've done the steps below as of 5/4/2016 with success.

1. Go to http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/finfo?name=www/downloads.wiki to view the history of the SQLite downloads wiki.
2. Search (ctrl+f) for the version you want (ex. 1.0.91.0)
3. Select the commit ID and it will open that old version of the page complete with download links to source code as well as precompiled binaries and setups.

You won't always find the version in a search (ex. 1.0.98.0), but it should be reasonably easy to find the correct page by the surrounding versions/commits.

You can also check archive.org for the downloads page:
http://web.archive.org/web/20150101000000*/http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
Find the date that your desired version was released on from the [SQLite news page](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki) (you may need to pick the next archive date after that). Select your desired link (sometimes the download page was archived, more ofter it seems like it was not). If the download page was not archived, edit the address bar to remove the archive.org-related info and you should be able to navigate directly to the SQLite download page for that version.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you are looking for binaries. Note that in some cases (eg .104) the commit log doesn't mention the version so you may have to poke around.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [link](http://www.sqlite.org/getthecode.html) to the official website and under "3.0 Obtaining Code Directly From the Version Control System" you can read further directions:

- get the list of release check-ins (this [link](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/timeline?t=release&n=0))
- choose the required check-in
- download source code archive

The oldest release available now is from 
2007-08-13.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to point out that https://www.sqlite.org/download.html only links to the most recent release, but a page always linking the current release combined with [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) preserving every (well, hopefully) version of said page, is all you need to download your favorite release:

http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Given that the binaries themselves have not been removed, of course, but fortunately they seem intact to me.
In fact, I just downloaded SQLite 3.9.2 through this page:
http://web.archive.org/web/20151231190003/https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get all release of SQLite from https://www.sqlite.org/chronology.html, this page contains the history of SQLite releases