# Compile sqlite3-devel 3.35.4 on CentOS 7

Tags: sqlite, centos7, proj

I am trying to upgrade my sqlite3-devel to 3.35.4. I can download and install the sqlite binary for the standard sqlite3 program but I cannot find a way to get the development version of sqlite3 version 3.35.4.

I need to update Proj to Proj8 which requires sqlite3 => 3.11

CentOS repos only support sqlite3 3.7.17.

How can I get sqlite3 3.35.4 "dev" or "devel" installed on CentOS 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install `gcc` and `wget`:

```
sudo yum install gcc wget
```

Then have a read at [Where can one find source archives of old SQLite versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615213/where-can-one-find-source-archives-of-old-sqlite-versions) to find out how to download a specific version of SQLite in `.zip` format.

Try the `.tar.gz` archive for Linux (I think the `.zip` is for Windows).

So for your version 3.35.4, the `.tar.gz` download link will be at: https://www.sqlite.org/2021/sqlite-autoconf-3350400.tar.gz

The file naming convention of the above path was from looking at the latest `.tar.gz` download link from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html.

Download the `.tar.gz` archive:

```
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2021/sqlite-autoconf-3350400.tar.gz
```

Extract it:

```
tar -xvf sqlite-autoconf-3350400.tar.gz
```

Make a `build` directory and change directory to it:

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

Run the `configure` script

```
../sqlite-autoconf-3350400/configure
```

Compile:

```
make
```

Install it:

```
sudo make install
```

Read carefully the output as it'll tell you where it installs to.

Confirm the version:

```
$ grep Version /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc
Version: 3.35.4
```

Comment: Hey there. Followed this to the letter. sqlite3 installed. (Libraries have been installed in: /usr/local/lib).  But still seeing `Requested 'sqlite3 >= 3.11' but version of SQLite is 3.7.17` error when installing proj.  Are there extra steps required? Error suggests ` Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable` or `set the environment variables SQLITE3_CFLAGS and SQLITE3_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config`... Any clues?

Comment: You might already have another version of SQLite installed? Try `rpm -qa | grep -i sqlite` to check.

Comment: Fixed by adding : ```ENV SQLITE3_CFLAGS="-I$sqliteDir/include" \ SQLITE3_LIBS="-L$sqliteDir/lib -lsqlite3"```